# Spatial interpolation with kriging or nearest neighbor method?

Tags: python, interpolation, spatial, kriging

This is an open question concerning interpolation of data.

My starting point is a couple hundred XYZ points that unevenly spaced, i.e. a point cloud.

I want to use kriging to give the Z values to the points in the area defined by

`gridx = np.arange(0.0,300,20)`

and

`gridy = np.arange(0.0,300,20)`

I want to be able to smooth the curves as needed. I have had success with the nearest neighbor in the past in ArcGIS but I am sure there is also a method to do this in python. I have tried using PyKrige but found there wasn't much I could tweak and the slopes were abruptly reverting back to the average Z value.

Best regards,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rather use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) which contains a python version of DACE, the popular kriging algorithm initially implemented in Matlab.

Plenty of other algorithms are also available for regression/interpolation, clustering, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries do an automatic optimization of the parameters but it is better you know the properties of your physical problem. In Python, I showed an example in 2D [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892146/geographic-interpolate-in-python/64385792#64385792) that uses [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/) platform.